# Index signature missing in type: why is this an error?

Tags: typescript

Take the following typescript:

```
type Primitive = undefined | null | boolean | number | string;

// A POJO is just supposed to be your typical object, with nothing 
// fancy, but where we don't exactly know what's in it.
interface POJO {
    [key: string]: Primitive | POJO;
}
```

Okay, so the POJO is just supposed to represent some generic object, but a nice simple one. Might be something I'm going to `JSON.stringify` or whatever. Now here's the offending code:

```
// Some functions implemented elsewhere...
declare function post(path: string, data: POJO): Promise<Response>;
declare function getToken(): string;

type LinkOrMessage = {link: string} | {message: string};

function specialPost(path: string, data: LinkOrMessage): Promise<Response> {
    const body = {
        ...data,
        token: getToken(),
    };

    // Error: see below...
    return post(path, body);
}
```

The error is:

```
Argument of type '{ token: string; link: string; } | { token: string; message: string; }'
is not assignable to parameter of type 'POJO'.

Type '{ token: string; link: string; }'
is not assignable to type 'POJO'.

Index signature is missing in type '{ token: string; link: string; }'
```

Wat? Moreover, if we change the `LinkOrMessage` type so that it's not a union, e.g. simplify it to just `{link: string}`, the error goes away! Same if we simplify to just `{message: string}`. So clearly each type in the union is assignable to `POJO`, yet the union is itself not?

Can someone shed some light on this behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since TypeScript 2.0 there is such a thing as an [implicit index signature](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/7029) which lets you assign certain objects of types without index signatures to variables of types with index signatures.  But the rules for when to infer an implicit index signature are a little [questionable](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15300) (in that some people question them).  In particular, there seems to be something going on with the interaction between [implicit index signatures and the spread operator](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17849).

I think the good news for you may be that the particular issue you are seeing is probably a [bug](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16694) introduced in TypeScript v2.4 and fixed in TypeScript v2.6.1.  The not-so-good news is that v2.6.1 isn't out yet; you can try to compile against [`typescript@next`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Nightly-drops) to see if it is cleared up.

Good luck!